# Looking for free/cheap Analytics Software like Statcounter

Tags: analytics

Does anyone know of any Analytics Software similar to Statcounter that is free (hopefully) or cheap? I have used Statcounter in the past and it's very helpful, however, it only allows information on that past 500 visits for free. Their paid version is tiered based on traffic, each tier has caps (data past x amount of visits isn't shown) which is a huge turn off.

With Google Analytics, it's a huge pain to show correlation between two set of data:
ie. I can see how many visits I get from New York and I can see how many visits I get to a certain page, but finding out how many visits to a certain page I get from New York? Forget about it!

Does anyone know of anything that meets my needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually get the data you want out of Google Analytics but you either need to use an Advanced Segment or a Custom Report.

With an Advanced Segment you can set up a filter for "New York" and most of the reports will just contain this data.

You can create a Custom Report that shows you visits to each page split down by region.

If you want to check out a different analytics package then a popular alternative to Google Analytics is piwik. It's free and open source but you need to host it yourself and I haven't used it enough myself to know how good it is.